# Update table-data with data from another table

Tags: mysql

Im trying to update a table with data from another table, the relation between the two tables ,
is a one-to-many relation. I have stubbed out a example here:

```
UPDATE
    foo f
INNER JOIN 
    bar b 
ON 
    b.fooId = f.Id 
SET
    f.something1 = b.barSome1,
    f.something2 = b.barSome1, 
    f.something3 =  b.barSome1, 
    f.something4 = b.barSome1
```

But my example only takes me half way, 
What I want to do is to select the top 1 bar based on latest 
bar.post_date or bar.Id or check if bar.barSome1 (lets say its a varchar) is null or empty.

As it is now it's some internal ordering of my bar's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you'll need to add a `WHERE` clause to limit which `foo` rows are modified.

```
UPDATE
    foo f
INNER JOIN 
    bar b 
ON 
    b.fooId = f.Id 
SET
    f.something1 = b.barSome1,
    f.something2 = b.barSome1, 
    f.something3 =  b.barSome1, 
    f.something4 = b.barSome1
WHERE 
  /* only the latest foo.Id */
  f.Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM foo)
  /* Or f.barSome1 is NULL or an empty string */
  OR (f.barSome1 IS NULL OR f.barSome1 = '')
```

To do it by newest `post_date` use a construct like:

```
WHERE
  f.id = (SELECT id FROM (SELECT id, post_date FROM foo HAVING post_date = MAX(post_date)) AS maxpost)
  OR (f.barSome1 IS NULL OR f.barSome1 = '')
```

### Update

To modify all rows of `foo` with matching criteria from a single row of `bar`, you can use a join against a subquery without an `ON` clause.  Test this out first with a SELECT statement.  *I've never tried anything like this and accept no responsibility if it destroys your `foo` table.* :) Backup first.

#### Test the JOIN

```
SELECT f.*, barsub.*
FROM 
  foo f
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM bar WHERE Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM bar)) barsub
```

#### The UPDATE should work the same way

```
UPDATE foo f
/* subquery returns one row so all rows of foo are joined to it */
JOIN (SELECT * FROM bar WHERE Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM bar)) barsub
/* no ON clause */
SET
   f.something1 = barsub.barSome1,
   f.something2 = barsub.barSome1, 
   f.something3 = barsub.barSome1, 
   f.something4 = barsub.barSome1
```

Comment: ok, i knew that one. But if i want to do my WHERE on the bar instead of the foo, i have edited my question, sry for the typo

Comment: @loddn So you intend to update one row of `foo` based on the criteria of `bar` (or more for the NULLs), or update all rows of `foo` with the one matched row from `bar`?

Comment: the later, -update all rows of foo with the one matched row from bar?

Comment: Good enoght, had to add a OB clause